# problem on almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let {$X_i$} be iid with finite second moment.
Let $Y_n = \frac {2} {n(n+1)}  \sum_{i=0}^n i*X_i $, n$\ge$1
Show that $Y_n \to E(X_1) $

I tried to define $Z_i = \frac {2} {(n+1)}  i*X_i $
Then $Y_n = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n Z_i} {n}$. Then if we can show that $Y_n \to E(X_1)$ a.s,then by Levy's theorem the required result will hold. How to show a.s convergence?

Comment: Instead of $Z_i$, it should be $Z_{i,n}$, right? You can use [SLLN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) then.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Wouldn't an application of SLLN need the $Z_i$ to be iid?

Comment: $Z_{i,n}=\frac{2i}{n+1}X_i$ are independent but not identically distributed. But you can see that their second moments are finite and so, $Y_n-E(Y_n)\to 0$ a.s. and you can easily see that $E(Y_n)=EX_1,\ n\ge 1$. Actually there is another requirement on the variance. See [Kolmogorov's strong law](http://planetmath.org/kolmogorovsstronglawoflargenumbers).

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Agreed. I didn't realize that the later result ($Y_n - E(Y_n) \to 0$) was also under the umbrella of results with title SLLN!